# How I can make a Compiled value from an Slick query wiht non-Rep pure values?

Tags: scala, slick

I have a query like this:

```
def getLatest( limit:Short, v:Rep[String] ) = ( for {
  (_,r) <- T1 join T2 on ( _.id === _.foreingId )
} yield r ).take( limit )
```

I can't make a "Compiled" value from this query because of "limit" ( A non Rep attribute in in argument-list ).
What can I do in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shoukd use `ConstColumn[_]` ( http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.1.0/queries.html#compiled-queries ) :

```
def getLatest( limit:ConstColumn[Long], v:Rep[String] ) = ( for {
  (_,r) <- T1 join T2 on ( _.id === _.foreingId )
} yield r ).take( limit )

val compiled = Compiled( getLatest _ ) // compiled( 10, "Hello" )
```